# CryptoJS weird encrypt/decrypt failure

Tags: cryptojs

I just want to encrypt a 128 bit code using AES-128 but it results in weird decrypt result.

It is set up this way so it can represent my real implementation:

```
var plain = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128/8);
console.log("plain: " + plain.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64));

var iv_wordArr = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128/8);
var salt = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128/8);

var key128Bits = CryptoJS.PBKDF2("12345678", salt, { keySize: 128/32, iterations: 1000 });

var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(plain.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64), key128Bits, { iv: iv_wordArr });

var dbKeyEnc = iv_wordArr.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64) + ":" + encrypted.toString();

salt = salt.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);

var splitted = dbKeyEnc.split(":");

key128Bits = CryptoJS.PBKDF2("12345678", CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(salt), { keySize: 128/32, iterations: 1000 });

iv_wordArr = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(splitted[0]);

var decrypt = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(splitted[1], key128Bits, { iv: iv_wordArr });

console.log("decrypt: " + decrypt.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64));
//console error: Invalid array length (because of decrypt wrong result)
```

I have checked step by step and iv, salt, key are alright. Problem comes when decrypting.

Answer (score 1):

After extense testing I found out that the problem was with the salt.

I assumed that this functions did the same thing:

```
var salt = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128/8);

salt = salt.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);

salt = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(salt); //correct one
```

But they are different. The second one is the one that keeps the same value.